# How do I configure service references without hardcoding configuration details win WinRT?

Tags: windows-runtime, service-reference

Our products consume WCF web services, and normally we handle switching between our dev, qa, local and production web services by changing the configuration in the web.config or app.config using the `<system.serviceModel>` section.

Now we are working on a WinRT application, and it does not appear to use a web/app.config.  Where do I configure this on a WinRT application?